# Load only highlight.js library using TypeScript, not default with all languages loaded

Tags: javascript, typescript, highlight.js

As the official highlight.js [usage document](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) suggests:

> The default import imports all languages! Therefore it is likely to be more efficient to import only the library and the languages you need:

```
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/highlight';
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript';
hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript);
```

I am trying to load just the `highlight.js` library, along with individual language modules so as to reduce my footprint for my TS app.

Using the `@types/highlight.js` declarations file, the only way (that I can find) to import highlight.js is like this:

`import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';`

Unfortunately, that loads the default export, which has all of the shipped languages loaded.

Looking into the highlight.js module, I want to do something like this:

```
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/highlight.js';
import * xml from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml';
...
hljs.registerLanguage('xml', xml);
```

so I only get the library itself, along with the only language I need (xml).

So far, I've been able to add these lines in a .d.ts file to get TypeScript to not complain about these imports:

```
declare module 'highlight.js/lib/highlight';
declare module 'highlight.js/lib/language/xml';
```

But of course, that means I lose my content assist when importing `hljs`. I could duplicate the content of `@types/highlight.js` into my own .d.ts file, but I'd really like to avoid that.

Is there any way to I can proxy the declarations from `@types/highlight.js` onto the module `highlight.js/lib/highlight'`? Or maybe some other approach I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating a Javascript file that requires only the languages I need:

myhighlight.js

```js
var hljs = require('../../../node_modules/highlight.js/lib/highlight');
hljs.registerLanguage('typescript', require('../../../node_modules/highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript'));
hljs.registerLanguage('json', require('../../../node_modules/highlight.js/lib/languages/json'));
module.exports = hljs;
```

And by importing this file in my Typescript code:

```js
import hljs from './myhighlight';

export class SomeClass {
  highlight(code: string) {
    return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the types by adding this line in the top of one of your `*.d.ts` files (e.g., `global.d.ts`)

```js
/// <reference types="highlight.js/types/index.d.ts" />
```